# Unable to create lxc container on centos "lxc_container: utils.c: get_template_path: 1128 No such file or directory - bad template: centos"

Tags: centos, containers, lxc

I am trying to create an lxc container on centos but I am running into the following error:
[user@sdn3-lnx-01 ~]$ lxc-create -t centos -n container1

lxc_container: utils.c: get_template_path: 1128 No such file or directory - bad template: centos

lxc_container: lxccontainer.c: lxcapi_create: 1223 bad template: centos

lxc_container: lxc_create.c: main: 274 Error creating container container1

[user@sdn3-lnx-01 ~]$

Could you please help me?

Comment: I don't know how to mark multiple answers as accurate. I was missing lxc-templates, so i installed them. Then I was supposed to use absolute path with -t option. Thank you @fat_cheng and @ Diego Mora Cespedes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
lxc-create -n container-name -t /etc/lxc/templates/lxc-centos --lxcpath=/var/lib/lxc/
```

You can also try:

```
lxc-create -n container-name -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-centos --lxcpath=/var/lib/lxc/
```

Basically, check which folder contains your template, `/etc/lxc/templates/` or `/usr/share/lxc/templates/`

Answer (score 16):

I am not familiar with centos,but on ubuntu,I met the same problem.and I fix it with execute:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc lxctl lxc-templates
```

maybe you need install some more packages.

Comment: To get LXC, LXC documentation, extra LXC tools and the default LXC templates just install the following packages. The templates are stored as shell scripts at /usr/share/lxc/templates .

dnf install lxc lxc-doc lxc-extra lxc-templates

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 5):

you can try

```
lxc-create -n ct1 -t download
```

& it will provide you with an inter-active solution to create the container & the list of templates & distributions supported

Comment: After sifting through a lot of pages on internet, this solution worked for me, finally. My host OS - RedHat 7.7 and I was trying to download LXC - CentOS 7 amb64. Worked.